# Upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 render error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, render

Today I made update of Android Studio to ver. 3.0 and after that I get error in layout editor:

[image]

This is my gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    def version = "2.4"
    def milestone = "1"
    def build = "5"
    def name = "WOMS" + "v" + version

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hr.aprox_it.womsmobile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig)
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/2'] } }
}

def appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            //def file = output.outputFile
            //def fileName = file.name.replace("app-debug.apk", "WomsMobile-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "v.apk")
            //output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }

        //def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        //def fileName = file.name.replace("app-debug.apk", "WomsMobile-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "v.apk")
        //output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Does anybody faced with this problem?
Seems that with each update of Android Studio and SDK old projects have problems.

**UPDATE**

in styles.xml i had changed:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and that solved problem... I guess... There is no any more rendering errors. I would like to hear from other how they solved this issue if they had it.

Comment: So you dont have any Linear Layout with alignParent stuffs?

Answer (score 1):

The `android:layout_alignParentLeft` attribute is only valid when your `View`'s parent is a `RelativeLayout`. In Android Studio 2.3, this was just a warning:

[image]

It seems that Android Studio 3.0 has upgraded this to an error (at least in terms of the Preview window). Just go ahead and delete this attribute; it's not doing anything anyway.

Comment: I already do that but didn't help. See my updated post what was the solution.